# How to migrate Room database with ArrayList field?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

There is an already created    @Embedded class Player. I want to add to it the    **ArrayList** field, which uses **@TypeConverters**, which converts my List to Gson when saving and back when loading.
        Please tell me how to make a request in the    void migrate ()
        method to add the list to an already existing instance of the Player 
        class.

```
@Database(entities = {Save.class}, version = 2)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(final SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Save ADD COLUMN trainingPower 
        INTEGER DEFAULT 5 NOT NULL");
        }
    };
}
```

Player class:

```
  public class Player
{
  @TypeConverters({AlbumsListConverter.class})
  private List<Albums> albumsList = new ArrayList();
  @Embedded(prefix="energy_")
  public Skills energy;
  public int energyCount;
  public int energyMax = 50;
  public String fameName;
  @Embedded(prefix="flow_")
  public Skills flow;
  public int imageID;
  int imagePers;
  @Embedded(prefix="mast_")
  public Skills mastering;
  @Embedded(prefix="mast2_")
  public Skills mastering2;
  private long money = 50;
  @Embedded(prefix="music_")
  public Skills music;
  private String name;
  public int ratingPosition = 1;
  public int reclameToken = 0;
  @TypeConverters({TrackListConverter.class})
  public List<Tracks> releaseList = new ArrayList();
  @TypeConverters({MessagesConverter.class})
  public List<Massages> messagesList = new ArrayList<>();
  private long reputation = 0;
  private int respect = 1;
...
}
```

class Save:

```
@Entity
public class Save
{
  @TypeConverters({ArrayConverter.class})
  public String[] AllTopicTracks;
  @Embedded
  private Player actor;
...
}
```

TypeConverter:

```
public class MessagesConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    public String fromMassagesList(List<Messages> messages)
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(messages);
    }
    @TypeConverter
    public List<Messages>toMessagesList(String data)
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Messages>>(){}.getType();
        return gson.fromJson(data,type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add code of Player class too in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you had used `@Embedded` for multiple variables. If `@Embedded` is annotated the variables of model class is treated as column for the same table. So for the case of multiple objects of same type you shoud use `TypeConverter` where the object can be converted to json string while saving and later retrieved as the object.

Instead of making embedded `Player`, create type converter for player and use it. By doing this you don't have to create separate type converter for objects inside player.

Comment: Can I do this in an existing save? The game has already been released and in the current version of the Player it is in this form ((to convert Player using TypeConverter, do I need to do certain actions in Room migration methods?